# Open modal through dynamically created button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamically created action button within a method. I've assigned an ID to the button, but I need to open a modal when the button is clicked. I'll then need to pass the button ID to the modal in order to retrieve the data. How can I open a modal within this method?

```
private static List<Details> LoadData()
{
    List<Details> infoObjs = new List<Details>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        // ...
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Details infoObj = new Details();
            infoObj.CommentsID = rdr["COMMENT_ID"].ToString();
            infoObj.Comments = rdr["COMMENT"].ToString();
            infoObj.Status = rdr["STATUS"].ToString();
            infoObj.Date = rdr["DATE"].ToString();
            infoObj.Action = "<a class='btn btn-warning' ID=" + infoObj.CommentsID + 
                "> <i class=\"fas fa-pencil-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>";
            //This button needs to open a modal.
            infoObjs.Add(infoObj);
        }
    }

    return infoObjs;
}
```

Comment: What type of modal? Bootstrap modal I guess based on your button classes. Do you have front end code for a modal made that you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery.

```
private static List<Details> LoadData()
{
    List<Details> infoObjs = new List<Details>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        // ...
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Details infoObj = new Details();
            infoObj.CommentsID = rdr["COMMENT_ID"].ToString();
            infoObj.Comments = rdr["COMMENT"].ToString();
            infoObj.Status = rdr["STATUS"].ToString();
            infoObj.Date = rdr["DATE"].ToString();
            infoObj.Action = "<a class='btn btn-warning' data-id=" + infoObj.CommentsID + " ID=" + infoObj.CommentsID + 
                "> <i class=\"fas fa-pencil-alt\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a>";
            //This button needs to open a modal.
            infoObjs.Add(infoObj);
        }
    }

    return infoObjs;
}
```

Create a parent div where you will append the `Action` property.

```
<div id="id"></div>
```

Assuming that this is returned by a ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "RequestHandler.asmx/LoadData",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
        $.each(response.d, function (i, obj){
           $("div#id").append("<div>" + obj.Action + "</div>"); 
        });   
  }
});
```

After that you can call a function that will bind all the event when that anchor is clicked, you can get the id via `data` attribute.

```
function setEvents() {
  $.each($("div#id").find("a.btn.btn-warning"), function(i, obj) {
    $(this).on("click", function (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       $("#modal").modal("toggle");
       $("#modalID").val($(this).data('id')); // this is a hidden field for the id in the modal
    });
  });
}
```

Then you can request again in the server then you pass the id from the hidden field.